# KSP Mods not loading after manual install win7

Tags: mods, kerbal-space-program

Manually installing KSP mods by unziping them into a KSP GameData folder is not working for me. Does anyone understand why this would be? As I understand it, you unzip the mod and drop its mod directory into GameData to look like this. And then restart KSP.

```
ls -l "/ms/c/Program Files (x86)/Steam/steamapps/common/Kerbal Space Program/GameData"
total 8
drwxrwx---+ 1 pete None 0 Jan 29 16:15 KerbalEngineer
drwxrwx---+ 1 pete None 0 Jan 24 21:44 MechJeb2
drwxrwx---+ 1 pete None 0 Dec 17 15:24 Squad
drwxrwx---+ 1 pete None 0 Jan 26 19:33 SquadExpansion
```

I installed both KerbalEngineer and MechJeb2 and neither worked. I used ckan.exe to reinstall KerbalEngineer and it worked, but I would rather install these plugins manually. KSP is a Steam managed ver `1.11.1.3066`.

If I inspect GameData  with [cigwin terminal](https://cygwin.com/install.html) the KerbalEngineer dir that `ckan.exe` installed looks exactly the same as what I had previously put there manually. Take a look at the `md5sum` checksums of the files from the unzip and the files that CKAN put in GameData.  They are the same files. Does anyone get what is failing or know how to debug this ?

**Contents of the zip (unzipped)**

```
$ md5sum /ms/c/Users/pete/AppData/Local/Temp/KerbalEngineer-1.1.8.3/KerbalEngineer/*
md5sum: /ms/c/Users/pete/AppData/Local/Temp/KerbalEngineer-1.1.8.3/KerbalEngineer/AssetBundles: Is a directory
5ffba2a1c5be09e579eb9bb4fe700aac */ms/c/Users/pete/AppData/Local/Temp/KerbalEngineer-1.1.8.3/KerbalEngineer/KerbalEngineer.dll
1e5a38f246306acfba5066a9ba990290 */ms/c/Users/pete/AppData/Local/Temp/KerbalEngineer-1.1.8.3/KerbalEngineer/KerbalEngineer.Unity.dll
0847444c8ef98576f0311179fd6b3a2d */ms/c/Users/pete/AppData/Local/Temp/KerbalEngineer-1.1.8.3/KerbalEngineer/KerbalEngineer.version

md5sum: /ms/c/Users/pete/AppData/Local/Temp/KerbalEngineer-1.1.8.3/KerbalEngineer/Parts: Is a directory
md5sum: /ms/c/Users/pete/AppData/Local/Temp/KerbalEngineer-1.1.8.3/KerbalEngineer/Presets: Is a directory
md5sum: /ms/c/Users/pete/AppData/Local/Temp/KerbalEngineer-1.1.8.3/KerbalEngineer/Settings: Is a directory
md5sum: /ms/c/Users/pete/AppData/Local/Temp/KerbalEngineer-1.1.8.3/KerbalEngineer/Textures: Is a directory
```

**Files installed by CKAN. The hashes match**

```
$ md5sum /ms/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Steam/steamapps/common/Kerbal\ Space\ Program/GameData/KerbalEngineer/*
md5sum: '/ms/c/Program Files (x86)/Steam/steamapps/common/Kerbal Space Program/GameData/KerbalEngineer/AssetBundles': Is a directory
5ffba2a1c5be09e579eb9bb4fe700aac */ms/c/Program Files (x86)/Steam/steamapps/common/Kerbal Space Program/GameData/KerbalEngineer/KerbalEngineer.dll
b68d7b2bb6663c06dc1f8a9ed892f476 */ms/c/Program Files (x86)/Steam/steamapps/common/Kerbal Space Program/GameData/KerbalEngineer/KerbalEngineer.log
1e5a38f246306acfba5066a9ba990290 */ms/c/Program Files (x86)/Steam/steamapps/common/Kerbal Space Program/GameData/KerbalEngineer/KerbalEngineer.Unity.dll
0847444c8ef98576f0311179fd6b3a2d */ms/c/Program Files (x86)/Steam/steamapps/common/Kerbal Space Program/GameData/KerbalEngineer/KerbalEngineer.version

md5sum: '/ms/c/Program Files (x86)/Steam/steamapps/common/Kerbal Space Program/GameData/KerbalEngineer/Parts': Is a directory
md5sum: '/ms/c/Program Files (x86)/Steam/steamapps/common/Kerbal Space Program/GameData/KerbalEngineer/Presets': Is a directory
md5sum: '/ms/c/Program Files (x86)/Steam/steamapps/common/Kerbal Space Program/GameData/KerbalEngineer/Settings': Is a directory
md5sum: '/ms/c/Program Files (x86)/Steam/steamapps/common/Kerbal Space Program/GameData/KerbalEngineer/Textures': Is a directory
```

Do they need to be registered in the registery?

Comment: What is "not working"? Crash? No mod seen? Also where do grab the zip? And finally did you restart the game after installing the files (might be obvious but we never know)? EDIT can you show the content of the folder too (AssetBundles, Parts,...)

Comment: @Goufalite well I get the mods from https://www.curseforge.com/ and my downloads MD5 match CKAN.  Initially Kerbal Engineer didn't load but now it does so not sure if my fault. MechJeb seems to have a different problem. It needs ModuleManager.dll installed into the GameData folder which is not documented in the mod. CKAN did that and things are working now.